# can nested iframes work?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to run jquery testswarm (http://swarm.jquery.org/) runner on samsung smart tv 2010 and 2011 in maple browser in order to test my application.

I built a widget which is the jquery testswarm runner. This work fine.

Jquery testswarm runner uses iframe to execute tests. One iframe works fine.

Then I'm trying to run some AngularJS tests (http://angular.github.com/angular-phonecat/step-8/test/e2e/runner.html) and that needs another iframe.

So to sumup - I've got a widget that uses an iframe with an iframe inside.

Any idea how to make that work?

Comment: I don't think IFRAMEs are fully/properly supported

Comment: thanks virorum, but what makes you say that?

Comment: The developer forums on SDF are full of people having problems with IFRAMEs - most comments seem to suggest there is at least a cross-domain security issue when trying to use IFRAMEs that point outside of your app

Answer (score 0):

iframes are not fully supported on any samsung smart tvs.
Check out the [Samsung Forum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=3193140890a213d3)